# Convert Redis Mass Insertion Protocol Format independent of OS

Tags: bash, docker, redis

I am trying to perform Redis mass insertion using the command `cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe` as mentioned in https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert.

The data format on macOS has to be converted so that mass insertion could be performed with `cat ${FILE} | perl -i -p -e 's|[\r\n]+|\r\n|g' | redis-cli --pipe`.

However, the above command does not work on a Linux environment (or a docker environment with the container built from an alpine based image). Instead, the following command has to performed `cat ${FILE} | sed 's/\r*$/\r/' | redis-cli --pipe`.

Is there a command that would work in both environments?

**EDIT:** Attached the following:

1. Redis Mass Insertion script on Alpine Linux: https://gist.github.com/francjohny/f2b13b4cfc147e07e52824ec88ba3781
2. Redis Mass Insertion script on Mac OS: https://gist.github.com/francjohny/b57756a1e0124dd562959ca5ece2a32b
3. Redis Protocol Format data file: https://gist.github.com/francjohny/0c21f32d9902809b215f4e92f5e6a9f1
4. `➜ head ouput.rpf| xxd - Mac OS` : https://gist.github.com/francjohny/e1a646ab44e7edd7374d28e9ca400711
5. `➜ head ouput.rpf| xxd - Alpine Linux`: https://gist.github.com/francjohny/252904928ded4c045448d12b205228df

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and add the output from `head -e data.txt | xxd` as generated on both systems, so we can see what your line endings currently look like.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry but did you mean `head data.txt | xxd` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've attached the requested files. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

From the data you have added, it seems you just have linefeeds separating your lines, whereas Redis requires carriage return followed by linefeed. So basically, you want the equivalent of the `unix2dos` program, which is not included in macOS. However, macOS does include Perl, so you should be able to use:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/\r\n/' data.rpf | redis-cli --pipe
```

It works fine on my Mac.

**Original Answer**

You appear to have mixed line endings in your various environments. I would imagine this Perl would replace any number of carriage returns and line feeds in any mixture with a single carriage return and linefeed like Redis requires:

```
perl -pe 's|[\r\n]*|\r\n|' data.txt | redis-cli ...
```

If not, please answer my question in the comments.

Comment: Sorry but this does not seem to be working on Mac OS and errors out with `exit status 1`. On Linux, mass insertion does not happen `errors: 0, replies: 0`.

Comment: By the way, you should get in the habit of double-quoting `bash` variables - in case, for example, they are filenames with spaces in them. E.g. `cat ${FILE}` should really be `cat "${FILE}"`

Comment: Also, note that `sed` is perfectly able to read a file itself without an unnecessary `cat`, so `cat ${FILE} | sed ...` should really be `sed ... "${FILE}"`

Comment: Thanks for these pointers Mark. Really appreciate them. Coming back to my original question, I would ideally like a single script which would work on both Mac and Linux. I know these commands (perl and sed) would individually work on their respective OS. But is it even possible to have a single script which would work on all platforms?

Comment: The same, single command I gave should work on both machines you mention. If it doesn't, please say which doesn't work and what happened.

Comment: This perl command works on both machines without error. On macOS, mass insertion is successful and I get `errors: 0, replies: 23009` but on Linux I get `errors: 0, replies: 0`.

Comment: On Linux, only this command: `sed 's/\r*$/\r/' "${FILE}" | redis-cli --pipe -h "${HOST}"` gives `errors: 0, replies: 23009`

Comment: Mmmm, ok. So the problem is either that the Perl command generates the wrong output on Linux, or that the Redis command on Linux is different from the one on macOS. Agreed?

Comment: So, run the same Perl command that I gave you with the same data file on both macOS and on Linux, then compare the two output files on macOS with `opendiff  Linux.txt macOS.txt`

Comment: And compare the two versions with `redis-cli -v` on each machine.

Comment: I figured out the problem, the `perl` command was not available on the Linux docker image (golang:1.10.1-alpine3.7), hence giving `errors: 0, replies: 0` after Redis Mass Insertion. Gosh! That was a lot of effort. Thanks a lot Mark! You're the best! You made my day!

Comment: Cool! Glad you are sorted!